# a 32 bit application is giving error of unload jre on the 64 bit java installed machine

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit

I have a `32 bit` application on `64 bit` machine and its installed into the Program X86 folder while Java1.6 (64 bit) is already installed on the same machine. When i run this application it gives error **"unable to load jre"**?

Please help me out how we can solve this problem without installing the 32 bit jre.

Comment: is classpath set up properly. Is it a problem with this application only or all java applications are having this problem

Comment: i have observed with all 32 bit application.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, I think your Java1.6(64 bit) is installed on the same machine, **but in the Program Files Folder is it?** And your 32 bit application in installed on the same machine, **but in the Program FileX86 Folder is it?**

If so that is the problem only that, your application does not find proper path for jre.

I think the problem is with your classpath, set the classpath according to your machine.

OR another way just install 32 bit jre on the same machine.

I recommend you to go for **32 bit jre installation**.

See this [article](http://www.pugetsystems.com/blog/2011/01/13/windows-7-64-bit-running-32-bit-applications/) for more help.

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui What?

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui So you can follow the answer

Comment: You are right that
JAVA1.6 is in Program files and my application
is installed in Program File X86.
But this application is running some more 64 bit machine and working fine.

Comment: You have any access to change classpath?

Comment: Is problem is Solved?

Comment: Thanks for your help yeah problem is solved by the installing 32 bit JRE on that system.

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui So now you can mark this answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 64-bit JVM(JRE), it won't load 32bit libraries, and vice versa.So you cannot do this without installing 32bit JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation in my environment. My Eclipse required 64bit JRE where as there were some applications running which needed 32 bit JRE . So it was easy for me to fix . I changed the eclipse ini file and point the 64 bit JRE. And in the PATH variable I set the 32 bit PATH .

If possible then check that the application can take the 64 bit JRE path from some configuration file or not otherwise you have to set PATH for 32 bit.